# I can not read the data on Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I use firebase functions for push notification triggers.

I can send notifications but I cannot read some data when the trigger launches.

I tried usual firebase database functions but they didn't work.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

let fcm = ''
exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/xxx/userInformations/{uid}/')
    .onWrite((change:any) => {
    // console.log(change.before)
      const payload = {
          notification: {
              title: 'Kahve Falı',
              body: 'Falın geldi!',
      }
    }
    admin.database().ref('/xxx/userInformations/{uid}/fortunes')
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot:any) => {
      console.log('snapshot.val()')//I want to get that snaphot.val()

      });
      fcm = change.before._data.fcm;
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcm, payload);
    });
```

It doesn't read that snapshot. It returns null or undefined with different ways. 
And I can not make this line like that;
`.then((snapshot) => {`

If I don't put `:any` it gives me an error on VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mistaking two parts of your code.

---

First you have:

```
exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/xxx/userInformations/${uid}/')
```

This declares a Cloud Function. When you deploy this code with Firebase, it recognizes this Cloud Function and interprets the string literal `'/xxx/userInformations/${uid}/'` as the path that this code needs to trigger on. It puts the values after `/xxx/userInformations` in the path into a parameter called `uid`.

---

Next you have:

```
admin.database().ref('/xxx/userInformations/${uid}/fortunes')
```

This is regular JavaScript code, in which case `'/xxx/userInformations/${uid}/fortunes'` is just a string that is sent to the Firebase client. Since `$` is not allowed in a path, the Firebase client raises an error.

You probably want the path to include the *value* of the `uid` parameter, which you can do with:

```
admin.database().ref(`/xxx/userInformations/${context.params.uid}/fortunes`)
```

So the changes:

1. Use backticks to mark the string, so that it's interpreted as a [ES6 Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
2. Use `${context.params.uid}` in there, to get the value of `uid` that was used to trigger the code.

This requires that you define `context` in your Cloud Function declations, like:

```
.onWrite((change:any, context: any) => {
```

Comment: You are a great person! Thank you very much! I hope you will live an awesome and happy life. Thank you so much man! 
Your answer is very clear and not just code, also knowledge.
Anyway, I love Firebase, fyi!

Comment: You're welcome. :) Don't forget to also upvote @AbdulhaqShaq's answer, as they pointed out the template string literal problem initially.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in template literal  `${expression}`. You are not providing **uid** correctly.

Use template literal if you are using ES6 or you can use + like concatenate the `uid` with `url`.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

let fcm = ''
exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/xxx/userInformations/${uid}/')
    .onWrite((change:any) => {
    // console.log(change.before)
      const payload = {
          notification: {
              title: 'Kahve Falı',
              body: 'Falın geldi!',
      }
    }
    admin.database().ref(`/xxx/userInformations/${uid}/fortunes`)
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot:any) => {
      console.log('snapshot.val()')//I want to get that snaphot.val()

      });
      fcm = change.before._data.fcm;
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcm, payload);
    });
```

Comment: I get that error;
`"/xxx/userInformations/${uid}/fortunes". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`

Comment: That means you didn't use backticks, and the `${uid}` is sent to the databse as is (which makes it an invalid path).

Comment: when I use backticks, I can not deploy t. I get this error `src/index.ts:15:58 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'uid'.
15     admin.database().ref(`/xxx/userInformations/${uid}/fortunes`)` @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: and why this is working if this providing wrong? `functions.database.ref('/xxx/userInformations/{uid}/')`

Comment: The line that declares your Cloud Function is parsed by Firebase when you deploy the code, and Firebase reads the literal string and determines what to trigger on. The line *inside* the function with `admin.database()` is just regular JavaScript code. To get JavaScript to replace the `${uid}` with its value, you must put it in backticks.