# How to delete unique id the children on Firebase Functions in RealtimeDatabase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I used to the firebase functions for deleting real-time database values. When directly writing the path it works, but It never reaches all the data.

Path: `/users/hatayberkay1234/consuming`. İt works for deleting hatayberkay1234's values.

Second Path ( does not work ): `/users/{usersid}/consuming`. This works on the server side. But It can not delete all userid's consuming children. It gives me an only message. It works. But my database still is the same.

I tried: `/users/${usersid}/consuming`. It is not work.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


 exports.herbesdkonbes = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {
   
   var adaRef = admin.database().ref(`/users/{usersid}/consuming`);
    adaRef.remove()
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Remove succeeded.")
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
      });
 
    });
```

My purpose is: Delete all data user's consuming children in my realtime database every 1 minute.

Also, I checked on StackOverflow [I can not read the data on Firebase Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746246/i-can-not-read-the-data-on-firebase-functions) . İt is not working. How can I fix it?

I am using node.js 18. version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the child nodes in order to delete them one by one.

You are looking to delete all child nodes of the `consuming` node for each user, so you will need to first retrieve the `users` node and then iterate over each child node to delete the corresponding `consuming` node.

Example:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.herbesdkonbes = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {
  const usersRef = admin.database().ref('users');
  usersRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      const userId = childSnapshot.key;
      const consumingRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/consuming`);
      consumingRef.remove()
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`Successfully removed consuming data for user ${userId}`);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(`Failed to remove consuming data for user ${userId}: ${error.message}`);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I am so so thank you Mr. paul. I searched for it for 2 days. It works perfectly. I am glad now. :)  Do you have any tutorials on this topic?